# Upload a raster in PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis

I know this might be a similar question to many others. I have been prompting multiple questions here and on Google but I can't figure it out. I have a raster and I have uploaded it into PostGIS with the following code:

```
raster2pgsql -s 28992 -I -M r69hn1.tif -F -t 1000x1250 schema.table | psql -d database -U postgres -p 5432
```

I am not using -C because it gives an error and I learned in other questions that removing it from the code makes it work; and it does load it in.

Then I am trying to open the data in QGIS using DBManager. There it gives me the message that I have the wrong raster type. The error message is in Dutch and not searchable. I have not found anything similar to my exact problem. The data I am trying to use is downloadable from the following link: 
http://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/ahn2/extract/ahn2_05m_ruw/r69hn1.tif.zip

The data is coming directly from the PDOK governmental services and is thus a trustworthy link. It is a tile from the AHN 2 height data.

My question is: Is there something wrong with my way of loading in the raster into PostGIS or with visualising it into QGIS. And further, what is wrong and how do I fix it?